# Creating a Macro That Can Run on Any Excel Sheet That I Open

Tags: vba, excel

I have to export data from software to excel frequently to generate reports. I'd like to write a few macros to make this process more efficient. How can I make these macros available to run on any spreadsheet that's open?

Comment: Store the macros in your Personal Macro Workbook and use ActiveWorkbook/ActiveSheet in your code.

Comment: Perhaps overkill, but you can also look into making an add-in out of your macros: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg597509(v=office.14).aspx